# Mass modify all php files on my server

Tags: ssh, php

I would like to delete a php code on all my php files on my debian server.
indeed I would like to get rid of a line:

```
eval(base64_decode("DQplcnJvcl9yZXBvcnR"));
```

It's present in many of my phpfiles.
That's why I would like to find a script which is going to look it up in all my php files and replace itwith nothing?
Do you have any idea how i could do that ?
I know how to do it on windows with some software (notepad++ is very useful) but no idea how can I do that in a command line through ssh

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C shell, you could do something like this:

```
foreach i ( `find -name "*.php"` )
   sed '/^eval(base64_decode("DQplcnJvcl9yZXBvcnR"));$/d' $i > $i.new
   mv $i.new $i
end
```

In bash, it would look like this:

```
for i in $(find -name "*.php"); do
   sed '/^eval(base64_decode("DQplcnJvcl9yZXBvcnR"));$/d' $i > $i.new
   mv $i.new $i
done
```